# XCode: __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ causes errors

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

This line of code works perfectly well when compiling for debug, ad hock or release:

`NSAssert(managedObjectModel, @"%@ %s shall create a model", self, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);`

But, if I try to Analyze or Profile instead, this line (and others like it) causes the following error:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation

Short of commenting out the asserts, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/Tasks/AssertMacros.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000063-BCIFBACA) it may be more appropriate to use `NSAssert2` in the case you have above because you are using four parameters instead of two.

Comment: Can you think of any reason the preprocessor only complains on some type of builds?